# Debian sysctl config not persisting on reboot

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sysctl, conntrack

I am running ubuntu 14.04:

```
Linux WEBLB3 3.13.0-79-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 14:27:58 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have modified the /etc/sysctl.conf file to set sysctl settings on reboot, it contains this value:

```
net.nf_conntrack_max = 2147450880
```

When running `sysctl -p` the connection track value is set appropriately. However, when the system reboots and `/etc/init/procps.conf` runs to set the system control vars from `/etc/sysctl.d/*` and `/etc/sysctl.conf` the `nf_conntrack_max` value does not get set appropriately and falls back to the default of 65535.

When I boot the server it takes ~15 seconds for `sysctl -a` to produce an output that contains the `nf_conntrack_max` value, so I am wondering if a race condition exists that is causing the `/etc/init/procps.conf` script to run and set the values too quickly.

I can write an upstart script that runs `sysctl -p` after sysctl finishes initializing but that feels like a terrible hack to me.

How can I ensure that all values in `/etc/sysctl.conf` get set appropriately on reboot?

Comment: load conntrack module at boot from initrd.

Comment: @IporSircer can you explain a little more

Comment: `echo nf_conntrack >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules ; update-initramfs -u`

Comment: Thanks @IporSircer Ive done this, however the problem still exists